# VB.NET replacing text in a word document, including a TextBox

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm trying to replace some placeholder text in a word document using my VB.NET code. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim aDoc As Word.Document

'Start Word and open the document template.
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True

'Load Invoice Template From Resource File
Dim myTempFile As String = Application.UserAppDataPath & "\mytemp.docx"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(myTempFile, My.Resources.InvoiceTemp, False)
aDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(myTempFile, , , True)


oWord.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting()
oWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
With oWord.Selection.Find
    .Text = "[iOrder]"
    .Replacement.Text = bwOrderID
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
oWord.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)

For Each oCtl As Word.Shape In aDoc.Shapes
    If oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
        oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Replace("[iOrder]", bwOrderID)
    End If
Next
```

This code executes correctly, with no errors, but it doesn't find "[iOrder]" in the textbox. However, if I then go to the word file and press `ctrl` + `F` for find and replace, the search criteria specified in the code is there, if I then click replace, it correctly replaces "[iOrder]" with the `bwOrderID` string.

I must be missing something here?

**Update 1**

I've updated my code to:

```
For Each oCtl As Word.Shape In aDoc.Shapes
            If oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
                oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Invoice: " & oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Replace("[iOrder]", bwOrderID)
            End If
        Next
```

This is working correctly, however I am losing my formatting. Is there a way to keep the formatting? The word "Invoice:" is a different colour to the "[iOrder]" and I'd very much like to keep it like that if possible.

**Update 2**

I have got the "Find/Replace" working, but I have a formatting issue as a result. Before the Find/Replace, the formatting of the textbox is like this:

[image: Before Code Runs]

Code:

```
For Each oCtl As Word.Shape In aDoc.Shapes
            If oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
                oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.FormattedText.Text = oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.FormattedText.Text.Replace("[iOrder]", bwOrderID)
            End If
        Next
```

This is what the result is after the above code runs:

[image: After Code Runs]

I have lost the alignment of the whole string and the color of the [iOrder] section that has been replaced. Is there a way of preserving this formatting?

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Is there anything in ***aDoc.Shapes*** ie. is the for loop iterating anything? Also is the if-clause in the loop finding the type of ***msoTextBox***. Also shouldn't you set the value the replace-call is returning back to the text-property?

Comment: Yes i've debugged (sorry, should have been more clear). The `aDoc.Shapes` loop is iterating and it does find a textbox and runs the enclosed `oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Replace("[iOrder]", bwOrderID)` code, but it doesn't find the text to replace (it is there). As for changing the text, i'll check that as it makes sense

Comment: Shouldn't the code just be this? `oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Replace("[iOrder]", bwOrderID)` Don't you only want to replace the string called "iOrder"?

Comment: @alstonp Yes, that works correctly, but it still strips out formatting, is there any way to replace the text without stripping the formatting out. Using the MS Word Find/Replace tool doesn't strip out formatting

Comment: You might have to re-apply the formatting, you can do this manually:  `oCtl.TextFrame.TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);`

Comment: @alstonp your example does not compile unfortunately